# VB.NET difficulties serializing classes with attached events

Tags: vb.net, events, serialization

Surprised this question has not been asked yet here, but here goes:

Serialization in VB.NET is a bit of a pain. If you use the standard Serializable() attribute, and attempt to serialize a class that has events which are attached to handlers, it will attempt to serialize the handlers as well.

Coming from a C# background I am not used to dealing with this problem, and the best solution I can find is using a class off of CodeProject.

However I'd rather not change the object inheritance structure for this idea.

What is the standard way to do Serialization of classes created in VB.NET?

I have heard of removing all handlers, serializing, then re-adding all handlers, but couldn't that lead to events firing and not getting handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, the solution is to apply the NonSerializedAttribute to the event's backing field, using the `field:` prefix on the attribute.  Unfortunately, VB doesn't support the `field:` trick, so you need to make the event's backing field explicit, and apply NonSerializedAttribute to that.  [Rocky Lhotka has sample code for this.](http://www.lhotka.net/WeBlog/CommentView.aspx?guid=776f44e8-aaec-4845-b649-e0d840e6de2c)

Unfortunately it does look rather verbose and tedious, since now you have to spell out the add, remove and raise methods for each event.