# Can't call Serialize() on instance of serializable singleton class in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I have a VB.NET singleton class which implements `Serializable`:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<Serializable()> Public Class CoordinateHistory
    Private Shared _thisInstance As CoordinateHistory

    Private gpsHistory As Dictionary(Of DateTime, GpsTimeCoordinate)
    Private gpsTimes As List(Of DateTime)

    Public Event NewStatusInformation(statusInfo As String)

    Protected Sub New()
        gpsHistory = New Dictionary(Of DateTime, GpsTimeCoordinate)
        gpsTimes = New List(Of DateTime)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function getInstance() As CoordinateHistory
        If _thisInstance Is Nothing Then
            _thisInstance = New CoordinateHistory
        End If

        Return _thisInstance
    End Function

    Public Function getHistoryCount() As Integer
        Return gpsHistory.Count
    End Function

    ' bunch of other class functions below...
End Class
```

My problem is that I can't actually call `.Serialize()` on the instance of this class, like all of the examples online show. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to ask: what serialization mechanism are you using?

Comment: I'd like to do binary serialization, but XML would be fine if that's easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is your Protected Sub. If you change it to Public, you may be able to Serialize correctly.

**Update**

I didn't have any issues serializing the default instance using a BinaryFormatter:

```
Dim abData As Byte()

Using oStream As New MemoryStream
    Call (New BinaryFormatter).Serialize(oStream, CoordinateHistory.getInstance())

    abData = oStream.ToArray()
End Using
```

or an XMLFormatter:

```
Dim sData As String

Using oStream As New MemoryStream
    Dim oSerializer As New XmlSerializer(CoordinateHistory.getInstance().GetType)

    oSerializer.Serialize(oStream, CoordinateHistory.getInstance())

    sData = Encoding.Default.GetString(oStream.ToArray())
End Using
```

Perhaps it is the serialization framework you are using?

Comment: I don't think that's it. I tried it, and I still can't call `CoordinateHistory.getInstance().Serialize()` (or just call `.Serialize()` on my actual instance).

Comment: Updated the response with sample code serializing in both XML and binary format.

Comment: Ah, one comment: when I tested this locally, I did not have GpsTimeCoordinate, so if it doesn't serialize for you using the methods I added to my answer, then the problem is going to be in that class.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your code and see if that helps. Perhaps I was just doing something daft when attempting to serialize...

Comment: Your code worked, although I also had to use the suggestion that @DaveM wrote below: remove all the event handlers before serialization and de-serialization. Of course, I also had to make GpsTimeCoordinate serializable (which I was forgetting). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue could be your classes public event. There is an article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/serializevbclasses.aspx) that describes the issues of serializing VB.NET classes with events and how to work around them.

**Edit:** See also this possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2150286/229858).

Comment: Interesting... this looks like a potential pitfall. I'll take a look and see if this does the trick. Looks like I may have to implement `ISerializable`...

Comment: Wish I could give you 50% credit, since the link you gave that suggested removing event handlers before serialization solved part of my problem. Thanks!